# How to template tag for @property in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-2.2

I defined field in air with `@property`. this is my `@property` field:

```
 @property
    def points(self):
        if self.pk:
            return  self.questions.all().aggregate(Sum('point'))['point__sum']
        else:
            return 0
```

Then I create template tag for `verbose_name` in django template: 
from django import template

register = template.Library()

```
@register.simple_tag
def verbose_name(instance, field_name):
    """
    Returns verbose_name for a field.
    """
    return instance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name.title()
```

When I use :

```
{% verbose_name exam "prices" %}
```

raise this error:

```
Exam has no field named 'prices'
```

How can I define `verbose_name` for `@property` and then use template tag for show `verbose_name` of this `@property?

Comment: As the error says, the model does not have a `prices` field because you have created a property not a field. You could catch the exception and return `field_name.title()`.

Comment: How can I do that? @Alasdair

Comment: look up try ... except in python.

Comment: Is it possible to tell me the answer ? @dirkgroten